# Help on simple comparison of means

Tags: anova, mean, sample-size, statistical-power

I have two groups (control and experimental). I want to test whether increased irrigation will affect clutch size of lizards. In order to do this, I need to have separate plots within the irrigated areas and within the control areas, in order to fence off the lizards. I am hoping to do a power analysis and determine how large my sample size needs to be. For instance, I could fence off four individuals in five different irrigated areas and fence off four individual in five different control areas....
(4 individuals in 5 plots for irrigated and 4 individuals in 5 plots for control)=40 individuals
My first question is, what type of analysis would I carry out? ANOVA? Or is this a nested design? Can I compare the mean of all lizards in the irrigated vs control? And also compare within irrigated and within control? 
My second question is, once I know which test, how do I determine sample size needed to see a true effect?

I'm probably over thinking this! :)

Answer (score 1):

- This feels like an ANOVA to me. A single factor ANOVA. You could do
  two-way ANOVA, but I'm not sure what your other factor is. Treatment
  is a factor. But location could be the other? i.e. the 10 blocks you
  are dividing up the area into. Then you would have to be able to
  randomly assign treatment within the blocks that you divide.
- You could just do 20 irrigated and 20 control, but not sure that's
  what you want. If not this is like a randomized block design.
- As of right now you do not have a nested design. If you imagine your
  setup as just 20 irrigated and 20 control, and you took the other
  factor (besides treatment) to be the individual lizards, then a
  nested design would be if you then asked...Does clutch size increase
  between male and female lizards consistently differ? Then you could
  have, $$E[Y] = SEX + SEX/LIZARD + TREATMENT$$
- Yes you can compare the individual means. Given the one-way ANOVA
  setting, if we can reject $H_0$ then we know that at least one of the
  factor level means is different. Ideally, we’d like to know which of
  the factor level means is different and in what way they are
  different. For this you can do pairwise comparisons with confidence
  intervals.
- In a two-way ANOVA setting you have factors A and B, and then you have the factor levels, a and b. So we have ab total treatments under study and if all of these are included in the study we have a complete factorial study where a two-way anova with 5 and 4 levels for the two factors gives 5*4 = 20 total levels and we need a minimum of 20 observations.

I may come back and edit this more but I'd like to hear from some other people too.

Comment: Upvoting in order to (hopefully) at least award half the bounty. I don't think some of the points are correct, but on the other hand there are some good comments in there.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. Feel free to comment on changes and I can edit. I'm no anova expert, but it just kind of felt right here.

Comment: For a full bounty I'd be looking for something with better justification than feelings. I wouldn't say I'm an expert either, but I think you'd need to consider than within-plot there'd be more similarity than across plot (e.g. consider this in the case of the controls), implying that it's not simply one-factor fixed effects anova; there should be some accounting for the "within plot" similarity (at the least some tendency to be higher or lower together ... implying at the least some form of intraclass correlation)

Comment: The reason this didn't get the auto-award of the half-bounty in the end was because mine was the only upvote; it requires at least two upvotes for it to go through.

Comment: @Glen_b No problem. I just wanted to share my thoughts and maybe hear from other people.